# How to implement show more and show less for HTML string in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have to show article content as 'show more' and 'show less' instead of Load More and that article content is present as HTML string. I need to implement show more and show less for HTML string.

I've done some research to see if there any examples to assist me with my question, but with no luck so far, All the examples I stumbled upon, were for pagination.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: articleDetailObject.customTemplate }}></div>
```

Thanks a lot for any help that is given.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-show-more-text

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way of doing this react.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App({ string }) {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = React.useState(false);

  const displayString = showMore ? string : string.slice(0, 100);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {displayString}
      <a style={{ color: 'blue' }} onClick={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}>
        {showMore ? ' Show Less' : ' Show More'}
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-joliot-f8j1n

Answer (score 0):

class App extends Component {

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        displayBio: false
    };
    this.toggleDisplay = this.toggleDisplay.bind(this);
}
toggleDisplay() {
    this.setState({
        displayBio: !this.state.displayBio
    });
}
render() {
    var bio = this.state.displayBio ? ( <
        div >
        This is true false condition <
        button onClick = {
            this.toggleDisplay
        } > Show Less < /button> <
        /div>
    ) : ( <
        div >
        <
        button onClick = {
            this.toggleDisplay
        } > Show More < /button> <
        /div>
    );
    return ( <
        div > {
            bio
        } <
        /div>
    )
}
```

}